# PySide.QTreeWidget reads file in Maya when pressing ctrl+v on it

Tags: python-2.7, pyside, maya, qtreewidget

I have a script for Autodesk Maya 2016 that shows a GUI that contains a Tree Widget in it. The problem is that when I select this widget and press ctrl+v, I get next message in the script editor:

> // File read in  0.19 seconds. //

Here is the code on how I initialize the Widget Tree:

```
[...]
self.presetsTree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
self.presetsTree.setEnabled(True)
self.presetsTree.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.presetsTree.setProperty("showDropIndicator", False)
self.presetsTree.setObjectName("presetsTree")
self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.presetsTree)
[...]
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.presetsTree, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemSelectionChanged()"), Dialog.selectNewPreset)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.presetsTree, QtCore.SIGNAL("activated(QModelIndex)"), Dialog.doNothing)
```

I connected to the 'activated' signal with the hope that the read stops happening (blind try), but it makes no difference. Also in this GUI there is no functionality that loads any file.

Does someone have an idea why this is happening, and how I can avoid this?

Edit: I found out that on the QTreeWidget (as well as on Maya's main window) it just pastes whatever is on Maya's clipboard when pressing ctrl+v. Now I need a way to either overwrite ctrl+v when this widget is active, or delete Maya's clipboard.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you press CTRL-V

Comment: When the TreeWidget is focused I want nothing to happen when Ctrl+v is pressed.